# NDBI formula for Landsat 8

Tags: landsat-8, landsat-5

The formula for NDBI for landsat 8 is (NIR-swir)/(NIR+swir).
I am confused if it is (Band5-band6)/(Band5+band6) OR (Band5-band7)/(Band5+band7)?

(For Landsat 5TM, NDBI formula is (Band5-Band4)/(Band5+Band4), and wavelength of band 5 is between 1.55-1.75.
So, by refering the wavelength, I am guessing, below formula to be correct for Landsat 8.

(Band5-band6)/(Band5+band6), but I want to be sure.
Please help me clear my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not 100% familiar with the NDBI Index, but found an article here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273886729_Built-up_area_extraction_using_Landsat_8_OLI_imagery

Specifically on Page 14 that describes the NDBI as:

> NDBI = (Band 5 - Band 4) / (Band 5 + Band 4)

Which is the original equation.

In order to get the NDBI for the Landsat 8 the author combines the Bands 6 and 7 and Bands 10 and 11 in a PCA.

> NDBI = (PCA B6,7 + PCA 10,11) - Band 5 /  (PCA B6,7 + PCA 10,11) + Band 5

Another article [Here](https://iradafmandaya.wordpress.com/2016/03/13/normalized-difference-built-up-index-ndbi/) describes the NDBI as

> NDBI = (B6 - B5) / (B6 + B5)

Another article [Here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b8ca/b8766c384ac4e210d4f02e27bd7136bad9dd.pdf) describes the SWIR for use in the NDBI as 1.57 - 1.65um. Which according to the Landsat Website, puts this as Band 6. Which corroborates the `B6-B5 / B6+B5` equations.

Comment: A database for remote sensing indices: https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/s-single.php?id=168

Answer (score -1):

For Landsat 8 you can follow this equation below

NDBI = Band 7 MIR or SWIR - Band 5 NIR / Band 7 + Band 5

Answer (score -1):

For Landsat 8 T1:
NDBI = (B1-B10) / (B1+B10)

Comment: Could you provide an explanation with context and insights? Welcome to stackexchange!

Answer (score -1):

NDBI = (Band 6 - Band 5) / (Band 6 + Band 5) for Landsat 8.

Comment: Can you please add more context and/or links to your answer. See the accepted answer already - how does yours differ or how do you know this is correct?